# Passing checked checkbox value to javascript through knockout.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Iam newbie with knockout js. I need to get the checkbox checked values from asp.net mvc cshtml to be passed to the javascript using knockout js. below is the code

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: AllAttrList'>
                        <tr id="trAttributeEditInd">
                            <td style="display: none;">
                                <span id="spnAttrId" data-bind="text: QuestionId"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="text-align: left;">
                                <input type="checkbox"  id="chkAttrName" style="margin-right: 20px"  data-bind="enable:!IsMandatory,checked:IsAssocToEngg && !IsMandatory" />
                                <span id="spnAttrNmInd" data-bind="text: QuestionText"></span>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
```

and in the javascript iam binding the value AllAttrList as below

```
 self.AllAttrList = ko.observableArray([
            { QuestionId: 1, QuestionText: "atr1", IsAssocToEngg: true, IsMandatory: true },
            { QuestionId: 2, QuestionText: "atr2", IsAssocToEngg: true, IsMandatory: false },
            { QuestionId: 3, QuestionText: "atr3", IsAssocToEngg: false, IsMandatory: true },
            { QuestionId: 4, QuestionText: "atr4", IsAssocToEngg: false, IsMandatory: false },
            { QuestionId: 5, QuestionText: "atr5", IsAssocToEngg: false, IsMandatory: false },
            { QuestionId: 6, QuestionText: "atr6", IsAssocToEngg: false, IsMandatory: false },
            { QuestionId: 7, QuestionText: "atr7", IsAssocToEngg: false, IsMandatory: false },
            ]);
```

iam in need to get what are the checked values and their id's (here it is questionid's). I have tried to loop through AllAttrList but still not able to achieve to get the checked values. Can anyone help me to get the checked values using knockout JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Use @Html.RadioButtonFor in place of checkbox and bind with your model.
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SomeModelProperty, "value", new { data_bind = "checked: model",@class="input" })
on .js file-
var abc = function(model)
{
    ko.applyBindings(BindModel(model))
}
var BindModel = function(model)
{
var self = this;
self.SomeModelProperty = ko.observable(model.SomeModelProperty);
}

Now you can do two way data-binding like this : -
<span id="spnAttrNmInd" data-bind='text: {QuestionText:SomeModelProperty()=="value", "":SomeModelProperty()=="" }'></span>
```

Comment: Thanks mukul, but i need to use checkbox only and also to reterive array of checked values.